# Is there a way to check when someone's role was added? [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, discord.js

I'm trying to get the date when someone got a role, but I'm not sure how to do it and if there is really any way. I've been searching for this a really long time. I would love some help.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
let Bot = new Discord.Client();

async function GetDate(userid) {
  if (!userid) return message.reply('')
}

Bot.on("message", async(message) => {
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);
    
    if(cmd === `!GetDate`) {
      let User = args[0]
      
      message.reply(`${User} is a member since 2020-02-17`)
    }
});
```

I

Comment: You would have to search the audit log, but it can be done. That's not going to be an easy task, probably more than could be provided in a single SO answer.  I suggest looking over the official documentation for GuildAuditLogs.

Comment: It depends on how recently the role was added. If it's within the duration of the available audit log, then yes, but the audit log seems to have a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen the event [`guildMemberUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/WSEventType), then fetch audit log with type [`memberRoleUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AuditLogAction) and get the audit log entires.

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(oldMember.roles.cache.size < newMember.roles.cache.size) {
        const fetchedLogs = await oldMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE',
    });
    
        const roleAddLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
        if (!roleAddLog ) return;
        const { executor, target, changes} = roleAddLog;
        console.log(`Role ${changes[0].new[0].name} added to <@${target.id}> by <@${executor.id}>`)
    }
});
```

---

**V2**

Oh, so you can get role by ID and get role [`createdAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=createdAt)

```
client.on('message', message => {
    let targetRole = message.guild.roles.get('PLACEROLEID')
    if(targetRole) console.log(targetRole.createdAt)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I wanted. I want to check the date, when someones role was added.

Comment: Im edit my answer, you can get role by ID and get `.createdAT`, so its the date when role was created

Comment: I want to make something like, when you use a command !getinfo (user), it outputs when a user got the role. For example. !getinfo @CoolGuy#1234. It would output something like, CoolGuy#1234 got role called : "Member" at (date).

Comment: So you need to insert action of my first answer into database and then select it. 
Discord don`t chached date when some role was added to user. (with any simple solution). And 1 user can have  10, 20 , 50, 100 or 200 roles, so you must know wich role to track.